# Python regex with brackets

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a subset of strings like bellow:

```
CUSTOMER1 => {
[
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_1
    ],
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_2
    ],
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_3
    ]
]
}
CUSTOMER2 => {
[
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_4
    ],
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_5
    ],
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_6
    ]
]
}
```

I need to first capture contents between { and } and then put each of SOME_CONTENT in the separate index of an array.
What I have till now is :

```
{\s*\n(.+(?:\n*.+)*)}
```

But it does not work as expected.
My expected result is something like bellow:

```
[[CUSTOMER1, SOME_CONTENT_1, SOME_CONTENT_2, SOME_CONTENT_3],[CUSTOMER2, SOME_CONTENT_4, SOME_CONTENT_5, SOME_CONTENT_6]]
```

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
Please consider the following as an input string:

```
ok: [router2] => {
output.stdout_lines: [
[
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone,
D - Remote, C - CVTA, M - Two-port Mac Relay

Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
R1.example.com    Gig 4/0            136              R    7206VXR   Gig 3/0
SW2.example.com   Gig 3/0            153            R S I  Linux Uni Eth 2/0
],
[
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet2/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet3/0         192.168.61.101  YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet4/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
FastEthernet5/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
FastEthernet5/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
FastEthernet6/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
FastEthernet6/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
],
[
EIGRP-IPv4 Neighbors for AS(100)
H   Address                 Interface              Hold Uptime   SRTT   RTO  Q  Seq
(sec)         (ms)       Cnt Num
0   192.168.61.100          Gi3/0                    13 02:40:40   24   144  0  135
]
]
}
ok: [router1] => {
output.stdout_lines: [
[
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone,
D - Remote, C - CVTA, M - Two-port Mac Relay

Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
R2.example.com    Gig 3/0            164              R    7206VXR   Gig 4/0
SW1.example.com   Gig 1/0            130            R S I  Linux Uni Eth 1/3
],
[
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/0         192.168.61.100  YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet2/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet3/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet4/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
FastEthernet5/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
FastEthernet5/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
FastEthernet6/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
FastEthernet6/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
],
[
EIGRP-IPv4 Neighbors for AS(100)
H   Address                 Interface              Hold Uptime   SRTT   RTO  Q  Seq
(sec)         (ms)       Cnt Num
0   192.168.61.101          Gi1/0                    13 02:40:41  340  2040  0  135
]
]
}
```

Expected output:

```
[["router2","Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
    S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone,
    D - Remote, C - CVTA, M - Two-port Mac Relay
    
    Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
    R1.example.com    Gig 4/0            136              R    7206VXR   Gig 3/0
    SW2.example.com   Gig 3/0            153            R S I  Linux Uni Eth 2/0" , "    Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
    FastEthernet0/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    GigabitEthernet1/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    GigabitEthernet2/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    GigabitEthernet3/0         192.168.61.101  YES NVRAM  up                    up
    GigabitEthernet4/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
    FastEthernet5/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    FastEthernet5/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    FastEthernet6/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    FastEthernet6/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down", "    EIGRP-IPv4 Neighbors for AS(100)
    H   Address                 Interface              Hold Uptime   SRTT   RTO  Q  Seq
    (sec)         (ms)       Cnt Num
    0   192.168.61.100          Gi3/0                    13 02:40:40   24   144  0  135"], ["router1", "Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
    S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone,
    D - Remote, C - CVTA, M - Two-port Mac Relay
    
    Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
    R2.example.com    Gig 3/0            164              R    7206VXR   Gig 4/0
    SW1.example.com   Gig 1/0            130            R S I  Linux Uni Eth 1/3", "Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
    FastEthernet0/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    GigabitEthernet1/0         192.168.61.100  YES NVRAM  up                    up
    GigabitEthernet2/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    GigabitEthernet3/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
    GigabitEthernet4/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    FastEthernet5/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    FastEthernet5/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    FastEthernet6/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
    FastEthernet6/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down", "    EIGRP-IPv4 Neighbors for AS(100)
    H   Address                 Interface              Hold Uptime   SRTT   RTO  Q  Seq
    (sec)         (ms)       Cnt Num
    0   192.168.61.101          Gi1/0                    13 02:40:41  340  2040  0  135"]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get your expected output as a list so that you can iterate over it, etc.? Or do you want it as a literal string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the output as a list, would you please try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

s = '''
CUSTOMER1 => {
[
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_1
    ],
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_2
    ],
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_3
    ]
]
}
CUSTOMER2 => {
[
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_4
    ],
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_5
    ],
    [
        SOME_CONTENT_6
    ]
]
}
'''

l1 = []
for k, v in re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*=>\s*\{\s*\[(.+?)]\s*}', s, re.DOTALL):
    l2 = [k]
    for m in re.findall(r'\s*\[\s*(\w+)\s*]', v):
        l2.append(m)
    l1.append(l2)
print(l1)
```

Output:

```
[['CUSTOMER1', 'SOME_CONTENT_1', 'SOME_CONTENT_2', 'SOME_CONTENT_3'], ['CUSTOMER2', 'SOME_CONTENT_4', 'SOME_CONTENT_5', 'SOME_CONTENT_6']]
```

**[UPDATE]**
As for the updated input, would you please try (assuming the variable `s` is assigned to the input):

```
for k, v in re.findall(r'.*?\[(.+?)]\s*=>\s*\{.*?\[(.+?)]\s*}', s, re.DOTALL):
    l2 = [k]
    for m in re.findall(r'\[(.+?)]', v, re.DOTALL):
        l2.append(m.strip())
    l1.append(l2)
print(l1)
```

Comment: your answer is correct. could you please modify it according to the question UPDATE?

Comment: Thank for the feedback. Would you please provide the expected output for the update? The whole result is not necessary. Just a few elements will be good enough. My main interest is how I should handle the colons and whitespaces in the strings. Cheers.

Comment: dear @tshiono I updated the question to show the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for the update. But the output differs from *my* expectation. It looks like a formatted plain text rather than a python list.

Comment: dear @tshiono, the output is still a python list. it is ansible output. I need to have a list of lists like [["router1", output1 , output2 , output3 ], ["router2", output1, output2, output3]]

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm not sure its output meets your requirement. This is a staring point and your feedback is welcome.

Comment: thank you very much, it is working properly.

Comment: Good to know that. Cheers.